# SQL Server : print out cursor values

Tags: sql, sql-server, printing, cursor

I want to be able to print out or output the values from a cursor for my stored procedure's. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this. I need to output my values onto a sheet like a report about which customers have paid and which haven't. A comparison would be great.

Here are my stored procedures for the customers who haven't paid:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[AdminReport1] 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       booking.bookingID, booking.totalCost, 
       booking.bookingDate, booking.paymentConfirmation,
       customers.customersID, 
       customers.firstname, customers.surname,
       customers.contactNum
    FROM
       booking 
    INNER JOIN 
       customers ON booking.customerID = customers.customersID
    WHERE
       paymentConfirmation = 'False'
    ORDER BY 
       bookingDate ASC
END
GO
```

Here are my stored procedures for the customers who HAVE paid:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[AdminReport2] 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       booking.bookingID, booking.totalCost, 
       booking.bookingDate, booking.paymentConfirmation,
       customers.customersID, 
       customers.firstname, customers.surname,
       customers.contactNum
    FROM
       booking 
    INNER JOIN 
       customers ON booking.customerID = customers.customersID
    WHERE
       paymentConfirmation = 'TRUE'
    ORDER BY 
       bookingDate ASC
```

So I need a cursor to print out my values. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. An example with how to do this in code would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you would like to see at the end. Could you please clarify? I don't think you need a cursor. It should just be a matter of running the 2 procs. What are you comparing between the 2 procs? You could also just return your paymentConfirmation coloumn and have the one proc

Comment: I just want to print out my values so it looks more like a report. The cursor is a feature my tutor recommended to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not convinced this is the most efficient way to do it (it would be better for SQL Server to feed the data to something designed to make display data; SSRS or even to Excel), here is what I would do as a start:

```
--Create somewhere to put the proc data and fill it. This will give us something tangible to query against.
CREATE TABLE #NotPaid
(
  bookingID INT ,
  totalCost DECIMAL(7, 2) ,
  bookingDate DATE ,
  paymentConfirmation VARCHAR(50) ,
  customersID INT ,
  firstname VARCHAR(50) ,
  surname VARCHAR(50) ,
  contactNum VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #HasPaid
(
  bookingID INT ,
  totalCost DECIMAL(7, 2) ,
  bookingDate DATE ,
  paymentConfirmation VARCHAR(50) ,
  customersID INT ,
  firstname VARCHAR(50) ,
  surname VARCHAR(50) ,
  contactNum VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT  #NotPaid
    EXEC AdminReport1

INSERT  #HasPaid
    EXEC AdminReport2


--Variables for use in our cursor. I'm only loading one table up as a demonstration.
DECLARE @bookingID INT ,
@totalCost DECIMAL(7, 2) ,
@bookingDate DATE ,
@paymentConfirmation VARCHAR(50) ,
@customersID INT ,
@firstname VARCHAR(50) ,
@surname VARCHAR(50) ,
@contactNum VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @Library CURSOR

SET 
@Library = CURSOR FOR
SELECT bookingID ,
totalCost ,
bookingDate ,
paymentConfirmation ,
customersID ,
firstname, 
surname ,
contactNum FROM #HasPaid

--Run the cursor and print out the variables as we loop again. Any formatting will need to be done in here. Again, I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.
OPEN @Library
FETCH NEXT FROM @getProductID INTO @bookingID, @totalCost, @bookingDate,
@paymentConfirmation, @customersID, @firstname, @surname, @contactNum 

PRINT 'I''m a header line'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @firstname + ' Hasnt paid! His booking date is ' + STR(@bookingDate)
    + '. This is the middle part'
FETCH NEXT FROM @Library INTO @bookingID, @totalCost, @bookingDate,
    @paymentConfirmation, @customersID, @firstname, @surname, @contactNum 
END
PRINT 'I''m at the bottom'

CLOSE @Library
DEALLOCATE @Library

GO
```

This should give you a fairly good starting place.

In terms of general efficiency, it would be better to just have the one proc and you pass in the information you want out, so, pass in the fact you just want the Paids, or just want the NotPaids, or everyone. And just to be a bore about it, SQL isn't really the place to be doing this type of formatting. There are much better tools out there for this!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @G_B has a very good point about the views, it would make the query so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest staying away from cursors unless there is a specific valid reason for using them. You could simplify this slightly by having a `view` which has the columns you are looking for

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AdminReport] 
AS 
BEGIN

SELECT
    b.bookingID,
    b.totalCost,
    b.bookingDate,
    b.paymentConfirmation,
    c.customersID,
    customers.firstname,
    c.surname,
    c.contactNum,
    paymentConfirmation
FROM 
    booking b
    INNER JOIN customers c
        ON b.customerID= c.customersID
--Where
    --paymentConfirmation = 'False'
ORDER BY 
    bookingDate ASC

END
GO
```

And then you can just select the records paid records as

```
Select * from AdminReport where paymentConfirmation = 'TRUE'
```

and the unpaid ones as

```
Select * from AdminReport where paymentConfirmation = 'FALSE'
```